# How to write in file text more times?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working C#, WPF and has a homework about game multiple-choice which has a application, make a list questions and answers for user. I want to write in file.text not only one time.

I used this event:

[image]

This code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using( StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ĐỒ ÁN 2\ĐỒ ÁN 2\bin\Debug\Bo1.txt"))
    {
        File.WriteLine("dsCauHoi*Câu hỏi thêm*"+ txbcauhoi.Text.ToString()+ "*"+txbA.Text.ToString()+ "*"+ txbB.Text.ToString()+ "*" +txbC.Text.ToString() +"*"+ txbD.Text+ "*"+ txbAD.Text.ToString()+"/n");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Cảm ơn bạn đã đóng góp ý kiến");
    this.Close();
}
```

But it allow writing one times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append to the file, instead of recreating it *(default)*,

Use the [public StreamWriter(string path, bool append)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload to append to the file. *(Just add a true to the constructor parameters)*

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var filename = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ĐỒ ÁN 2\ĐỒ ÁN 2\bin\Debug\Bo1.txt";

    using(StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(filename, true))  // true for append..
    {
        File.WriteLine("dsCauHoi*Câu hỏi thêm*"+ txbcauhoi.Text.ToString()+ "*"+txbA.Text.ToString()+ "*"+ txbB.Text.ToString()+ "*" +txbC.Text.ToString() +"*"+ txbD.Text+ "*"+ txbAD.Text.ToString()+"/n");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Cảm ơn bạn đã đóng góp ý kiến");
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow then, hope you help others as well. Share your knowlegde to make the world a better place.

Answer (score 3):

Check signatures of `StreamWriter` constructor method.
You are passing only text file physical address to `StreamWriter`. So by default StreamWriter overwrites your text file. Pass true to append argument of StreamWriter constructor method like following.

```
using(StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ĐỒ ÁN 2\ĐỒ ÁN 2\bin\Debug\Bo1.txt", true))
{
    File.WriteLine("dsCauHoi*Câu hỏi thêm*"+ txbcauhoi.Text.ToString()+ "*"+txbA.Text.ToString()+ "*"+ txbB.Text.ToString()+ "*" +txbC.Text.ToString() +"*"+ txbD.Text+ "*"+ txbAD.Text.ToString()+"/n");
}
MessageBox.Show("Cảm ơn bạn đã đóng góp ý kiến");
this.Close();
```

Comment: it's really helpful ^^